# How do I print to stdout or a file using C++20 format library

Tags: c++, format, c++20, cout, fmt

As is well noted, the one thing that didn't make it into C++20's format library was a function that prints to standard out, or to a generic file stream.  We've been promised a `std::print()` to fill this need in C++23, but that doesn't solve the problem in the interim.

What options exist to solve this?

Comment: Simply `out << std::format(...)`, since `std::format` returns a string

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I'm specifically trying to avoid that for performance reasons. That will involve the unnecessary creation of a std::string, and the insertion of the entire payload into it, possibly in several chunks. If that exceeds the SSO size, that will have a significant overhead, since we're now talking heap allocation and deallocation, possibly multiple times if the string grows to be large.  See my answer for a better way.

Comment: You specifically said *`std::format`* in your question. Consider changing the title to '*...using C++20 <format> library*'

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question, the solution is actually very simple.  [`std::format_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to) can write to an output iterator, so all that's needed is the construction of a suitable iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <format>

int main()
{
    std::ostream_iterator<char> out(std::cout);  // Create an output iterator that writes to std::cout
                                                 // Replace std::cout with an ostream to write to a file
    std::format_to(out, "Hello {}!\n", "world");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this will, of course, become completely unnecessary if we get the promised `std::print()` in C++23.  But it is a valid interim solution.